# How to recover deleted data in SharePoint Online Excel

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

User deleted the data from Online excel, is there a way to recover the deleted data?

Answer (score 1):

If the document still exists, right click the document and navigate to "Version history" this should show a list of all previous versions of the document which you can restore from.

Or if the document itself was deleted, there is a site recycle bin which can be found through the cog in the top right of the page > site contents > recycle bin.